# What is happening when I run grep -lr "search terms" without the dot?

Tags: grep

If I run `grep -lr "search terms" .` on a huge directory tree I get my list of matching files almost instantly. But if I forget the dot, it will run possibly forever. What is it doing? Whenever I make that mistake, I have to ctrl-z and then kill the background process. ctrl-c only works half the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling grep with no file name or a single hyphen tells it to search the standard input. It's waiting for your input. If you type in a sentence that has your search term in it, it will return the matching section highlighted.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep